# script.onerror not throwing an error when url is incorrect

Tags: javascript

I have got the code below which should throw and error if the URL is incorrect. However nothing is actually happening, even though the URL is defiantly incorrect.

```
function loadApi() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapiss.com/maps/api/js?key={key}&libraries=geometry';
    script.onerror = function() {
      exit('MarvMap: Unable to load Google Map API, please check the URL.');
    };
    script.onload = function () {
      document.head.appendChild(this);
    };
  }
function exit(message = 'Exiting MarvMap') {
    throw new Error(message);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script isn't loaded until/unless you append the element to the DOM. If you do that, you see the error:

```
function loadApi() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onerror = function() {
        exit('MarvMap: Unable to load Google Map API, please check the URL.');
    };
    script.onload = function () {
        console.log("Loaded");
    };
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapiss.com/maps/api/js?key={key}&libraries=geometry';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

(I also habitually hook the handlers *before* setting the `src`, because it matters with images. But not with scripts.)

Comment: why does it matter with images to hook handlers before src?

Comment: @HimanshuTanwar: Because the instant you set the `src`, the browser is free to trigger the load event if (for instance) it has the image in cache, literally between the `img.src = x` and the following `img.onload = y`. "Triggering" = looking to see if there are handlers for the event and, if so, queuing calls to them on the event loop. But if there aren't any handlers, it doesn't have to queue any calls. That is, it's not allowed to *run* the handlers between those two lines of code, but it's allowed to *look* for them. (And this did used to happen. I don't know if it still does.)